# Is the nonnegative orthant isometric to itself under orthogonal mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, multivariable-calculus, isometry, dual-cone

**Problem description:**

*(Informal).* I simply want to know if there exists a *necessary and (or at least) sufficient condition* for an orthogonal matrix to map *every point* of the nonnegative orthant (say on $\mathbb{R}^m$) to itself.

*(Formal).* Let $\mathscr{D}_m = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in\mathbb{R}^m\,:\, x_i\geq 0,\ i=1,2,\ldots,m\}$. For a given $\mathbf{Q}$  an $m\times m$ real orthogonal matrix define the image $\mathscr{D}_m^{*} = \{\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^m\,:\, \mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{x},\, \mathbf{x}\in\mathscr{D}\}$. Is there a necessary and (or at least) sufficient condition on $\mathbf{Q}$ in order for $\mathscr{D}_m = \mathscr{D}^{*}_m$?

**Motivation/Context of the problem:** (Change-of-variable in Integration)

Let $\mathbf{S}$ be an $m\times m$ positive definite matrix. It is well-known that there exists an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ and a diagonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ such that $\mathbf{Q}^{\top}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{Q} = \boldsymbol{\Lambda}$. With this, we have the following equality of $m$-variate integration via the classic (multivariate) change-of-variable, noting that the absolute value of the Jacobian is $|\text{det}(\mathbf{Q})| = 1$,
$$
 \int_{\mathscr{D}_m} \exp\{\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{x}\}\cdot\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{x}\}\,\text{d}\mathbf{x}
=
 \int_{\mathscr{D}^{*}_m} \exp\{\mathbf{y}^{\top}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\,\mathbf{y}\}\cdot\exp\{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\}\,\text{d}\mathbf{y}
$$
where $\mathscr{D}_m$ and $\mathscr{D}^{*}_m$ are given in the (formal) problem description. The left-hand-side can be calculated easily if $\mathscr{D}_m = \mathscr{D}^{*}_m$ which gives our motivation of the problem stated above.

**Attempt:**

Honestly speaking, I failed to find from the web for a simpler explanation. I came across with the article of Barker and Foran *[Self-Dual Cones in Euclidean Spaces](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82320096.pdf)* with an abstract that contains the following line..

> ``...*We begin by giving necessary and sufficient for a cone to be the orthogonal transform of the positive orthant...''*

I humbly accept that I am new to this topic. It is even my first time to hear that the nonnegative orthant is a symmetric self-dual cone. I have basic Linear Algebra and Calculus as background. Hope anyone can help me with this.

**EDIT:** I found this link: [Find a nonnegative basis of a matrix nullspace / kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188406/find-a-nonnegative-basis-of-a-matrix-nullspace-kernel?rq=1) that relates to this problem.

Comment: There is something on this problem in the Perron-Frobenius theorem, do you know it? I am not too sure about this.

Comment: I am sorry. My answer is no. I'll try to search on that now. I am currently reading more background (introductory) material for the paper of Barker and Foran to understand the concepts which are really new to me. Maybe I could prove something about the necessary and sufficient conditions on the orthogonal matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem But now that I see it, I don't think it can really help you, sorry. Yours looks like a not-so-easy problem unfortunately

Comment: Perron-Frobenius essentially says that, if all entries of your matrix are $>0$, then you have an eigenvector in the positive octant.

Comment: It says here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#No_other_non-negative_eigenvectors that *some* matrices contain at most one positive eigenvector.. This is quite a sad news. Though I really don't know how to connect it yet to my problem.

Comment: Somehow, the problem is quite trivial if all the rows of $\mathbf{Q}$ are nonnegative. In this case $\mathscr{D}^{*}_m \subseteq \mathscr{D}_m$. The true problem lies when we permit negative elements in the rows.

Comment: If the rows of an orthogonal matrix are non negative then the matrix is the identity. I suspect that no matrix except the identity fixes the positive orthant.

Comment: I have searched through the web regarding Perron-Frobenius theorem..and here's a paper which, of course as for now, I'm struggling to learn..https://www.math.wisc.edu/hans/paper_archive/other_papers/hs156.pdf

the title of paper is "Matrices leaving a cone invariant" by Schneider and Tam

Comment: Well I was thinking the same thing..can you give some links about the diagonalization of orthogonal matrices? I can't find some decent sources. If $(\lambda_i,\mathbf{z}_i)$, $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ are the eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs where the $\mathbf{z}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{z}_m$ form an othonormal basis, then it would suffice to show that each $\lambda_i\geq 0$ and the rows of each $\mathbf{E}_i = \mathbf{z}_i\mathbf{z}_i^{\top}$, $i=1,2,\ldots, m$ are nonnegative since by spectral decomposition:
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{x}  = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_i \mathbf{E}_i\mathbf{x} \geq 0
$$

Comment: You say "map _every point_ to itself", but then you have $\mathscr D^*=\mathscr D$, which only means the whole set maps to itself (individual points may move). In the latter case, diagonal reflections obviously work. For example, if $m=3$, there is $$Q=[[0,1,0];[1,0,0];[0,0,1]]$$ ...Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: It's not necessarily reflexive (i.e., identity) when I say "to itself". I said "nonnegative orthant to itself". Yes, diagonal reflections are possible.

Comment: I don't see how $\mathscr D^*\subseteq\mathscr D$, unless $\mathscr D^*=\mathscr D$; orthogonal matrices are invertible. And why do you require non-negative eigenvalues, which excludes reflection matrices? @GiuseppeNegro -- Here's a non-identity rotation matrix with non-negative rows, which also fixes $\mathscr D$ : $$Q=[[0,1,0];[0,0,1];[1,0,0]]$$

Comment: I am just considering matrices with non-negative eigenvalues for a possible *sufficient* condition on $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Right, thank you. The corrected statement is: "every orthogonal matrix with non-negative entries is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)", and the corrected conjecture is that only the only orthogonal matrices that fix $\mathscr D$ are permutations.

Comment: In 3D, it's obvious that the positive octant (a "corner of a cube") has exactly 6 symmetries: 3 reflections, 2 rotations (120deg), and the identity. I believe this generalizes to nD, with all symmetries being compositions of reflections that swap 2 axes.

Comment: @Guiseppe Negro: Then, that solves the problem. Am I right?

Comment: Can anyone formalize some proof and put it as an answer so that we can finally close this problem?

Comment: I don't know how to formalize this, but the positive orthant is the convex hull of the positive coordinate axes, and the axes are the "edges" of the orthant, so they should have the same symmetries. A symmetry of the axes must send every axis to another axis, and must be invertible; these are indeed permutation matrices.

Comment: Here's a proof on nonnegative orthogonal matrices being permutation matrices:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322514/nonnegative-orthogonal-matrices